# remove prefix in all column names

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove the prefix from all column names in a dataframe.

I tried creating a udf and calling it in a for loop

```
def remove_prefix(str, prefix):
    if str.startswith(blabla):
        return str[len(prefix):]
    return str

for x in df.columns:
    x.remove_prefix()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `rename` method, which accepts a function to apply to column names

```py
def remove_prefix(prefix):
    return lambda x: x[len(prefix):]

frame = pd.DataFrame(dict(x_a=[1,2,3], x_b=[4,5,6]))  
frame = frame.rename(remove_prefix('x_'), axis='columns')
```

Comment: Same problem like `yatu` answer, if columns names start with `x` like `x_xa` it remove `x_x`. What is incorrect.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex `^` for match start of string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['pre_A', 'pre_B', 'pre_predmet'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('^pre_', '')
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, predmet]
Index: []
```

Another solution is use list comprehension with `re.sub`:

```
import re

df.columns = [re.sub('^pre_',"", x) for x in df.columns]
```

Comment: Hey @jezreal how can we do the same in pyspark

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) to strip the prefix from the column names, this way you avoid looping and checking which do contain the prefix:

```
# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['pre_A', 'pre_B', 'C'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('pre_')
```

Resulting in:

```
print(df.columns)
# Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

*Note*: This will also remove an occurence of `pre_` preceded by another, i.e. all the left side successive occurrences.

Comment: be careful, if column name contains value of prefix it also remove this characters... e.g. `pre_predmet`

Comment: Was trying to use same regex as u but apparently you can't with lstrip @jezrael. Guess I will just leave as a note

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace` in `list-comprehension`:

```
df.columns = [i.replace(prefix,"") for i in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can read file without headers, using `header=None`:

```
pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=filename, header=None, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove it using standard pandas API:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.removeprefix("prefix_")
```